# Java - jndi ldap slow search

Tags: java, performance, ldap, jndi, openldap

We are using javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext to connect and query an openLdap.

The problem is that we are getting com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapSearchEnumeration as the results, and looping it is really slow, like 5 SearchResult per second.

I also tried with the apache ldap api and im getting the same times, unless i bring less atributes but its still slow. To get 180 results it takes 10 seconds.

Code example of jndi ldap:

```
       Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://aplivolatil....:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=usuarioLector.....");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "9IVNOaQmEeE");
    env.put(Context.BATCHSIZE, "1000");
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
    LdapContext contexto;

    try {
        //contexto = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        contexto = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

        SearchControls controlesBusqueda = new SearchControls();
        String [] attrs = new String [] {"cn"};
        controlesBusqueda.setReturningAttributes(attrs);
        controlesBusqueda.setSearchScope(1);

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> resultadosObjetos = contexto.search("cn=usuarios-......",
                "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))", controlesBusqueda);


        while (resultadosObjetos.hasMore()) {
            resultadosObjetos.next();
        }
```

So, after investigation and several tests we found out that putting the jndi ldap environment property "batchsize" to 1000, the same delay goes to the search method instead of when looping the results. Which makes sense in a way that the api was going to ldap on every next() maybe. But why so much delay anyway ?

With rootDN goes super fast, 1 sec, could something be wrong with the user im using for searches ? which obviously is not the rootDN ?

Answer (score 1):

Apache has an LDAP API that they're working on. You can check it out [here](https://directory.apache.org/api/). Unfortunately, the documentation isn't very fleshed out at this point. A good number of pages on the [User Guide](https://directory.apache.org/api/user-guide.html) are empty, but you can fill in the gaps with a little intuition and some help from the [JavaDocs](https://directory.apache.org/api/gen-docs/latest2/apidocs/).

Even with the lack of good tutorials, I've used this API before and had pretty good luck with it. I'd suggest giving it a try at the very least and see if things improve.

Comment: i get the same time with apache ldap api, but what i noticed is that if i query less atributes the loop speeds up. As an example, 180 registers goes from 37 seconds to 10 seconds, that's better than getting all atributes. But i dont get it, why is so slow to loop the results anyway ? I confirmed its not going to ldap again, so am i missing something ? I will add the code example above.

Comment: Since it's going slow for both implementations, it leads me to believe that it has something to do with the actual data itself. Unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure how you would go about making the loop faster. I would suggest putting in timers to see which call takes the most time. Is it `cursor.next()`, the `Entry entry = cursor.get();`, or is it actually the `System.out.println()` call? Set up a logger to see which one is at fault, and to see if it's _always_ at fault, or just for certain values that it's looping through.

Comment: Ive also tested the same query on phpldapadmin and it takes 1 sec, so i guess its Java related. And it wasnt the loop, cause i put the jndi ldap environment porperty batchsize as 1000, and now the search method has the same delay, but the loop is instantaneous. I will update the question.

Comment: it was the user (security_principal) !! I dont know why, i ll keep investigating.

Comment: The rootDN goes super fast, 1 sec. What could be the problem with the user im using for searches ? which obviously is not the rootDN.